# Create rows to fill missing values grouping by date

Tags: r, tidyverse

Let's say I have such a data frame.

Here there are people, weeks and a number which is cumulative for the weeks passing by.

```
    df <- tribble(
  ~week, ~author, ~n,
  "W1",  "John", 1,
  "W1",  "Jack", 2,
  "W2",  "John", 2,
  "W2",  "Annie", 3,
  "W2",  "Peter", 1,
  "W3",  "Annie", 4,
  "W3",  "John",  3,
  "W3",  "Jack", 3
)
```

Now, what I'd like to do is group_by week, and have all the authors (Jack, John, Annie and Peter) for every week, keeping the number of last week in case there was no add up.

I can use `complete()` or `fill()`,to keep the number from last week, after `sort(df, week, author)`, I guess, but I don't understand how to add authors in case that week they haven't produced anything.

This is the result I'd like to see

```
df <- tribble(
  ~week, ~author, ~n,
  W1,  "John", 1,
  W1,  "Jack", 2, 
  W1,  "Annie", 0,
  W1,  "Peter", 0,
  W2,  "John", 2,
  W2,  "Annie", 3,
  W2,  "Peter", 1,
  W2,  "Jack", 2
  W3,  "Annie", 4,
  W3,  "John",  3,
  W3,  "Jack", 3,
  W3,  "Peter", 1
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out, I'll edit it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first `complete` the missing `author` from each `week`, `fill` them with previous value and `replace` `NA` values with 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  complete(week, author) %>%
  group_by(author) %>%
  fill(n) %>%
  mutate(n = replace_na(n, 0))


#   week  author     n
#   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 W1    Annie      0
# 2 W1    Jack       2
# 3 W1    John       1
# 4 W1    Peter      0
# 5 W2    Annie      3
# 6 W2    Jack       2
# 7 W2    John       2
# 8 W2    Peter      1
# 9 W3    Annie      4
#10 W3    Jack       3
#11 W3    John       3
#12 W3    Peter      1
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
Interestingly enough, in my code this worked in a weird way: I had 1s instead of NAs for new fields, and it wasing summing up progressively. Maybe that is because my week column was `date`, not sure.
I tweaked it a bit and this works very nice:

`group_by(df, week, author) %>%
  count() %>%
  group_by(author) %>%
  mutate (cumText = cumsum(n))
`